# Can't go back to former PHP-page

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have three PHP-pages. 1st lists several projects, 2nd shows buttons/alternatives to do with the chosen project and the 3rd page is for example a page that lets me edit the chosen project(because I've pressed the "Edit" button on page 2).

The problem now is that I can go back from the second page to the first page and see the content that should be showed, BUT when I press the back button when I am on page 3 to return to page 2 I don't get any content at all. What could the issue be?

**This is some of the code on page 2**

```html
<?php
    
$bild = (isset($_POST['pid'])) ? 
    "<img src=pic.php?pid={$_POST['pid']} width=100xp height=100xp/>" : '';
$val = (isset($_POST['pid']) && isset($_POST['project_name'])) ? 
    "<img src=pic.php?pid={$_POST['pid']} width=100xp height=100xp/> {$_POST['project_name']}" : '';    
$pid1 = $_POST['pid']; 
$pname = $_POST['project_name'];
$_SESSION['pid'] = $pid1;
$_SESSION['sesbild'] = $bild;
    
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
echo "  <h1>$pname</h1>
$bild

<br>

<form method='post' action='editproject.php'>
<input type='submit' value='Redigera projektinfo'>
</form>

<br>

<form method='post' action='dilemman.php'>
<input type='submit' value='Dilemman'>
</form>

<input type='submit' value='Ta bort projekt' onclick=\"return confirm('Vill du verkligen radera projektet? \\n\\nOBSERVERA att tillhörande data också kommer att raderas!');\">
</form>
"
 ;}  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you arrive on page two with some `$_POST` data from page one.  However, when coming *back to* page two from page three, there is no `$_POST` data.  Therefore the following line:

`if(isset($_POST['submit'])){`

causes page two to be blank.  You probably don't need that line at all or you need a more specific test.